# SQL Server 2005 upgrade SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

would it be possible to upgrade SSAS 2005 to SSAS 2008 only?

Answer (score 1):

Each product (SQL Engine, SSRS, SSIS, SSAS) can be upgraded separately.